# WordPress - "Author" dropdown menu doesn't remmeber who is the author

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added a filter to make it possible for regular users to be selected as authors of posts. It works well, after selecting an author and updating the post a user is assigned to it.

The problem is, after doing so - when you go to the front-end and then go back to back-end of that post then author dropdown menu switches back to admin (as if WordPress couldn't remember what it is set to, so if you update the post it's going to be assigned to admin again).

It seems as if wordpress is forgetting who was selected as an author. How can I modify the filter to make that dropdown menu remember who was chosen to be the author of a post?

```
add_filter('wp_dropdown_users', 'theme_post_author_override');
function theme_post_author_override($output)
{
  // return if this isn't the theme author override dropdown
  if (!preg_match('/post_author_override/', $output)) return $output;

  // return if we've already replaced the list (end recursion)
  if (preg_match ('/post_author_override_replaced/', $output)) return $output;

  // replacement call to wp_dropdown_users
 $output = wp_dropdown_users(array(
   'echo' => 0,
  'name' => 'post_author_override_replaced',
  'selected' => empty($post->ID) ? $user_ID : $post->post_author,
  'include_selected' => true
 ));

 // put the original name back
 $output = preg_replace('/post_author_override_replaced/', 'post_author_override', $output);

  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Feels a bit like you're trying to reinvent the wheel, check Co-authors Plus: https://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/

Comment: You are right, I used this plugin instead. Thank you, if you wish to post it as answer then I will select it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

This might have been solved but I just had the same problem and solved it so wanted to share the solution. The code above needs an additional line in line 4.
I hope it helps someone.

```
add_filter('wp_dropdown_users', 'theme_post_author_override');
function theme_post_author_override($output)
{
global $post, $user_ID; // <-- You need this line
// return if this isn't the theme author override dropdown
if (!preg_match('/post_author_override/', $output)) return $output;

// return if we've already replaced the list (end recursion)
if (preg_match ('/post_author_override_replaced/', $output)) return $output;

// replacement call to wp_dropdown_users
$output = wp_dropdown_users(array(
    'echo' => 0,
    'name' => 'post_author_override_replaced',
    'selected' => empty($post->ID) ? $user_ID : $post->post_author,
    'include_selected' => true
));


// put the original name back
$output = preg_replace('/post_author_override_replaced/',         'post_author_override', $output);

return $output;
}
```